# Scipyのminimizeで指定した制約条件が上手く効かない

Tags: python, scipy

scipyのminimizeで、以下のように制約条件を指定しても2番目の制約がうまく効かない（得られた最適解についてsum(abs(x-w0))が0.5を超えてしまう）場合、原因として何が考えられるでしょうか？

x、w0はn次元ベクトルでw0は初期値として設定しています。

```py
cons = (
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 0.50 - sum(abs(x - w0))}
)
```

Comment: ちなみに結果を見ると、以下のようになっているので、何らかの理由で最適化がうまく実行されてないせいでしょうかね？


message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'
success: False

Comment: ソースコード全体を載せてみてください。